# How to display a values in code-igniter table from controller?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a one array in code-igniter controller

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    echo $row['_source']['shape'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['cut'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['color'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['clarity'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['lab'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['polish'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['symmetry'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['stone_id'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['fluorescence'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['cert_no'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['_source']['location'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

which gives me two different bunch of values

In first bunch of values i got

**round  3X  D  IF  GIA  VG  G  id01  FNT  xy01  india**

In second bunch of values i got

**heart  2X  f  IF  IGI  VG  G  id01  FNT  xy01  china**

Now i want to display this all values in table in view part..

Comment: `$data['your_array'] = $array; $this->load->view('view_page', $data)` and now use `$your_array` in view page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First send your data to view as follows:

```
//Retrive your data here and put in  $result
$data['res']=$result;
$this->load->view('view_page', $data);
```

Then in your view page

```
<table>
<?php 
foreach($res as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['shape']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['cut']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['color']."<td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['clarity']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['lab']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['polish']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['symmetry']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['stone_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['fluorescence']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['cert_no']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['_source']['location']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";           
     }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: not working "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error

Comment: check `is_array($res)` is true or not?

Comment: problem is at sending the data array.silly mistake..it works now..:-)

Answer (score 0):

In controller :

```
$data['your_array'] = $array;
$this->load->view('view_page', $data);
```

View page :

```
<table>
<?php 
if(is_array($values) && count($your_array) > 0) {
    foreach($your_array as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['shape']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['cut']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['color']; ?><td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['clarity']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['lab']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['polish']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['symmetry']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['stone_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['fluorescence']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['cert_no']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['_source']['location']; ?></td>
        </tr> 
        <?php   
    }
}
?>
</table>
```